# C++ compilers for embedded programming

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, embedded

For desktop and server programming in C++, the most commonly used compilers are Microsoft C++ and GCC. What are the most commonly used compilers for embedded programming? Is it most typical to use a version of GCC or are other compilers more popular?

Comment: Are you referring to EC++ or standard C++?

Comment: That's a very good question, I hadn't previously known about EC++. I guess the answer is, either, or, how widely used is EC++ anyway? Wikipedia suggests it's kind of dead, is that true?

Comment: it often depends on the target platform. For ARM processors you can find both gcc and ARM-designed compilers for example.

Comment: @rwallace I've heard of it used in more of in a car brain-box type scenario, though it's prevalence with the amount of RAM we have now is probably made it obsolete now that you can have the little additional overhead of C++. So in short, it's probably not widely enough used to be considered or used now.

Comment: EC++ is a subset of C++, EC++ is only about enforcement of that subset; if you write code to the same subset using a C++ compiler, there is in fact *zero* additional overhead. The motivation for EC++ was largely to do with lack of a ratified C++ standard at the time of inception; since that no longer applies, EC++ is now largely irrelevant.  The same subset can be enforces with static analysis tools without needing any special compiler or compiler mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm working in embedded development and for most of our targets (ARM cores) we use GCC. For some exotic targets we need to use compilers provided by the manufacturers or 3rd party. The latter tend to provide acceptable support for C, but support for C++ is often poor.

IMHO the EC++ standard is nothing else than a good excuse for compiler manufacturers to keep their efforts low for C++ support, when it comes to template support (which often is the much better choice over RTTI) this 'standard' is just a bad joke.

Answer (score 2):

When programming embedded software on a microcontroller or microprocessor, most of the times you don't get to choose your compiler. You have to deal with the compiler provided by the manufacturer. Sometimes it actually *is* gcc. Sometimes, very popular chips get supported by several compilers, but don't count on it too much.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different IDEs for embedded programming. Some of them use gcc, others use its own compilers. Many manufactures distributes their own compilers like TI and Analog devices. Also there are some independent IDEs  with independent compilers like IAR, Keil, Code Sourcery.
Most popular compiler is gcc, but it is not most advanced. I've seen efficiency comparison for IAR, Keil and gcc. In most cases IAR was the best.

Comment: Microchip provides gcc with some architectures. But recently they seem to plan to replace it with an own for the 16-bit range